# Registering one's opinion with a low reputation?

Tags: discussion, comments

I'm only 14 years old (almost 15).  I am here because my dad is an active member, but I like to see what other people have to say and even learn from the well referenced answers.  If I see a good answer, I generally vote it up.  However, I I don't have enough reputation to really register my opinion on Skeptics.  I usually don't have much to say either, so I am afraid that I will always be stuck in this area of not being able to really be part of the ebb and flow of answers, just a silent agreement with those who give good ones.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Always good to see young skeptics!  Following facebook and such, I think I may know your dad as well.  :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Surely the *best way* of registering your opinion is to provide a great answer! But if you don't feel comfortable doing that, there are other considerations.

You don't need to down vote to register your opinion. Up votes have a much more dramatic effect than down votes. Compare:

- An up vote gives the recipient 10 reputation
- A down vote gives the recipient -2 reputation (and it costs you 1 point of rep)

So you already have access to the most powerful voting tool. The reason why down votes require a higher reputation is trying to prevent people from serially down voting out of spite.

Another tool you can use is comments. If you think a post has a mistake or an imprecision, a constructive comment can be a very good way of getting your point across.

You can see more info about what you can or can't do with your rep on [this page](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/privileges).

Answer (score 1):

Providing good answers if often a question of investing time into doing research. If you don't know enough about a topic to give an answer you can still learn something about the topic.
Research interesting questions yourself. It's a good habit.